# Vector errors in initialization and push_back of pairs

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to make a vector of pairs, a object in first and a list of object pointers in second. However, I keep getting this error that there is no matching function.

```
Query blank_query();
std::list<Movie_Data*> blank_list;
std::vector<std::pair<Query,std::list<Movie_Data*>>> vec (Hsize,std::make_pair(blank_query,blank_list));
```

I'm getting this error

```
hash_table.cpp:128:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::pair<Query, std::__cxx11::list<Movie_Data*> > >::vector(int&, std::pair<Query (*)(), std::__cxx11::list<Movie_Data*> >)’
  (Hsize,std::make_pair(blank_query,blank_list));
```

Another example

```
hash_tbl.push_back(std::make_pair(blank_query,blank_list));
```

Error

```
hash_table.cpp:177:61: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::pair<Query, std::__cxx11::list<Movie_Data*> > >::push_back(std::pair<Query (*)(), std::__cxx11::list<Movie_Data*> >)’
    hash_tbl.push_back(std::make_pair(blank_query,blank_list));
```

Comment: `Query blank_query();` is a function declaration, you want `Query blank_query;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a victim of a vexing parse. This line

```
Query blank_query();
```

actually declares a function named `blank_query`, that takes no arguments, and returns a `Query`.

You need to do something like:

```
Query blank_query{};
```

to create a `Query` object.

Comment: Interesting, should curly braces always be used when initializing a object with no parameters?

Comment: Yes, or you could do `auto blank_query = Query{};`, or assign a value of type `Query` of course.